# SweetAlert2 (swal) IE11 Angular 2, Overlay showing after popup

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Background overlay does not disappear even after the popup only in IE11. Working fine in chrome, safari, and firefox.

```
      swal({
            title: 'ERROR!',
            text: 'Please check email and/or captcha',
            type: 'error',
            timer: 2000,
            showConfirmButton: false
           }).catch(swal.noop);
```

**See Image**: [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdddP.png)

Comment: very common behaviour, the overlays dont remove nicely. You may have to remove the class of the overlay container on closing the popup manually to be sure that this type of irregularity does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for now: 
**Working with no issue on IE11**:

```
       swal({
            title: 'ERROR!',
            text: 'Please check email and/or captcha',
            type: 'error',
            timer: 2000,
            showConfirmButton: false
           }).then(() => {if (swal.isVisible() === true) {$('.swal2-container').remove() } }, () => {if (swal.isVisible() === true) { $('.swal2-container').remove() } })                     
          .catch(swal.noop);
```